# Is there a domain of discourse in which the trivial/nontrivial distinction breaks down?

Tags: meaning, difference

Let us suppose that we commonly imagine that problems have sets of solutions, wherein there are *empty* solutions, *trivial* ones, and then *nontrivial* ones. Add further that we have a relatively stable intuitive sense of this trichotomy: we can recognize trivial and nontrivial solutions "when we see them" (empty answers seem(!) discursively identifiable more readily, although I'm not sure why, or whether this is more a personal difference; perhaps it is a matter of having an intuition of emptiness such as collapses the intuition/discursion distinction, here).

But does this trichotomy hold for all types of problems? I had been thinking, for example, that almost all absolute truths, which do "exist" (I have almost no problem with the typical retorsion argument to this effect), are, however, trivial, but that the existence of God might be an example of a nontrivial absolute. Then, on the other hand, for the sake of divine simplicity, I started to wonder whether it would be more fitting to speak of God as transcending the trivial/nontrivial distinction in turn, of being "hypertrivial" (if that makes any sense). Although I haven't yet been able to attach much useful sense to such a turn of phrase, it is quite evocative and I would not feel amiss in thinking to attribute such a status to God-as-an-answer-to-a-problem, especially insofar as if I were to press my sense of divine simplicity more strongly than I tend to (but am tempted to).

Comment: In mathematics it may take a true expert to realize that something is trivial. Triviality depends on your perspective.

Comment: A few jokes about triviality in mathematics: https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2010/04/03/on-trivial-in-mathematics/ 'Two mathematicians are discussing a theorem. The first mathematician says that the theorem is “trivial”. In response to the other’s request for an explanation, he then proceeds with two hours of exposition. At the end of the explanation, the second mathematician agrees that the theorem is trivial.'

Comment: @causative my understanding of the topic is rather torn, since it seems like some mathematicians want to find triviality, like it's the target, whereas others seem to want to maintain the distinction, because it makes for more interesting targets. Yet there is a paradox, as per the joke you cite, since it is as if triviality-in-itself is already nontrivial, or then already "hypertrivial" (I don't think that's the best phrasing for it, "transtrivial" might be more along the lines of what I'm thinking, but it's kind of clunky). A strange antinomy, perhaps.